# jBPM: Can a form exists without a template

Tags: jbpm, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

I'm comparing Activiti's and jBPM's way of handling Human Tasks (User Tasks) and I wonder if there is a way of creating a form in jBPM that can be automatically rendered out of data input associations in BPMN process. In Activiti you can simply use `<activiti:field>` attribute, which handles everything. Can I somehow query jBPM's API for data input associations and their types?

Answer (score 0):

In jBPM if you don't define any form a form will be dynamically generated based on a template defined using FTL that will render your data inputs as text fields filled with the data coming into the task and empty text inputs for all the Data outputs defined in the task.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I'd like to use jBPM's API to render the form myself? How can I query the engine to get declared inputs and outputs for a task?